# Microsoft reporting services 2012 deployable to the cloud

Tags: azure, reporting-services, cloud

I have a quick question on microsofts reporting service. I know SSRS 2012 is their desktop version and they also have Azure reporting services, but what I would like to know is it possible to host the SSRS 2012 on the cloud and use this directly. I am picking up contradicting advice on the web with regards this, I am worried about using Azure because they limit you to using the Azure database.

What I'm looking to do, is to have a reporting service hosted on the cloud but without any restriction on data sources.

thanks
mark

Comment: Where would your other data sources be hosted?